# Why are we comparing numbers of array with median rather then mean in the question sticks lengths of CSES(question mentioned below)?

Tags: algorithm, math, mean, median

> There are n sticks with some lengths. Your task is to modify the sticks so that each stick has the same length.
>
> You can either lengthen and shorten each stick. Both operations cost x where x is the difference between the new and original length.
>
> What is the minimum total cost?
>
> Input:
> The first input line contains an integer n: the number of sticks.
> Then there are n integers: p1,p2,…,pn: the lengths of the sticks.
>
> Output:
> Print one integer: the minimum total cost.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
> 10
> 576256620 793841203 607061968 362964043 698782696 775664590 69510254 711292185 317067848 711901928
>
> Output:
> 1758621869

What I thought was that if we take mod of the value of all the numbers subtracted with mean(or mean+1) of the numbers and add them we should get the answer. But turns out we need to take median.
Can anyone explain why are we getting the answer through median?

Comment: For example 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100000

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, consider list `[a,b,c]`, which is sorted.

1. Their median = `b`. Total cost = `(b-a) + (b-b) + (c-b)` = `c-a`
2. Their mean = `(a+b+c)/3`. Let it be x. Total cost = `(x-a) + abs(b-x) + (c-x)`
   If you compute `(x-a)+(c-x)`, it'll evaluate to `c-a`. Thus the total cost becomes `(c-a) + abs(b-x)`, which will always be `>= (c-a)`.
   Thus the median is a better parameter.